# Which of this program can be multithreaded?

Tags: multithreading, malware-detection

I am a normal user and does not have strong background in programming.

I have a 64 bit, dual core machine (Dell Vostro 3400) and I *think* I can run multithreaded program with this machine (yes?)

The program that I think could be convert into multithreaded program is this:

http://code.google.com/p/malwarecookbook/source/browse/trunk/3/8/pescanner.py

Is possible to do so?
If yes, which part should being edited so that it will work?

Thanks.

Comment: How long is `pescanner.py` taking to run, and on what sorts of files? It doesn't *look* like it should be particularly slow as it is.

Comment: For the record, any modern machine can run multithreaded programs, though the biggest difference in performance will generally be noticed on multi-core/multi processor machines.

Comment: Malware scanners that check files are constrained by how fast they can read the file data off the disk.  Your machine has only one disk.  Multi-threading is not going to make it faster.

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading is **not** an easy subject.

I suggest you read up on some tutorials, see:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Basic-Threading-in-Python/
http://www.artfulcode.net/articles/multi-threading-python/

To answer the general part of your question, you can run multithreaded code an any machine newer than say 2000.
Your question is too broad though to answer without going into details on the code.

**My suggestion**
I suggest you try the tutorials first and write same sample programs, ask a specific question **with sourcecode**! if you get stuck.
That's a road I'd recommend rather than taking someone else's code and rewriting it without detailed knowledge of threads.